# Default case returns mutated state redux

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I am building a ETH portfolio tracker using ethplorer's API with React, redux-react and thunk middleware on the frontend. The main component of the store is an array of objects (tokens). You could see its reducer and actions below:

```
import {createToken, initializeTokens, deleteToken, replaceTokens} from '../services/tokens'

const tokenReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TOKEN':
      return state.concat(action.data)
    case 'ERASE_TOKEN':
      return state.filter(token => token.address !== action.data)
    case 'INIT_TOKENS':
      return action.data
    default:
      return state
  }
}

//Defining Actions
export const addToken = address => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const newToken = await createToken(address)
    dispatch({
      type: 'ADD_TOKEN',
      data: newToken
    })
  }
}

export const updateTokens = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const updatedTokens = await initializeTokens()
    await replaceTokens(updatedTokens)
    dispatch({
      type: 'INIT_TOKENS',
      data: updatedTokens
    })
  }
}

export const eraseToken = address => {
  return async dispatch => {
    await deleteToken(address)
    dispatch({
      type: 'ERASE_TOKEN',
      data: address
    })
  }
}

export default tokenReducer
```

Imported functions are being used to fetch tokens from the API and then save them into a local database. Another component of an action is a MarketCap filter (string) that I use to sort tokens according to their market cap (biggest to smallest, smallest to biggest or none). It has a super simple reducer and an action:

```
const mcReducer = (state='NONE', action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_MC_FILTER':
      return action.filter
    default:
      return state
}
}

export const mcFilterChange = filter => {
  return {
    type: 'SET_MC_FILTER',
    filter
  }
}

export default mcReducer
```

The problem begins when I start sorting tokens for display in the React component. While I do not intend to change the *tokens* state, and only want to change the array of displayed tokens, my *tokens* state neverthless changes to the sorted out one after I sort by the MC. So what happens is: programm dispatches SET_MC_FILTER => TokenList sorts tokens according to the filter => tokenReducer returns mutated state instead of the old one. I don't understand why it happens, since I don't dispatch any actions that should affect the *tokens* state here and by default tokenReducer should just return the state that was stored in it. Here is the last piece of code where the problem apparently happens:

```
const initTokens = useSelector(state => state.tokens)
const mcFilter = useSelector(state => state.mcFilter)

  const getDisplayTokens = inTokens => {
    switch (mcFilter) {
    case 'NONE':
      return inTokens
    case 'DESCENDING':
      return inTokens.sort(compareMCDescending)
    case 'ASCENDING':
      return inTokens.sort(compareMCAscending)
    default:
      return inTokens
  }}
  return(
    <div className='token-list'>
      {getDisplayTokens(initTokens).map(t =>
        <TokenTile token={t} key={t.id}/>
        )}
    </div>
  )
```

I have tried to track down the exact place where the *tokens* change with debugger and trace option of redux-devtools, but everywhere the tokenReducer instantly returns the changed state, and I have no idea why. Any bits of help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.sort()` mutates arrays in place. You should never try to call `.sort()` directly on arrays that were read from the Redux state.  You must make *copies* of the arrays and then sort them.

Also, note that you should use [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which will both eliminate mutations in reducers, and throw errors if you ever try to mutate code *outside* of reducers.

See https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux for a tutorial on how to use RTK correctly.

Comment: Thank you! Copying the array with `[...initTokens]` and performing sorting on it did help. I will implement RTK and figure out how to use it for the sake of abvoiding such headaches in the future